# Stop onCreateOptionsMenu() to be called from detached Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, menuitem, oncreateoptionsmenu

I know there is LOT of code but **please read the first paragraph** and go further if you need more info !  Thanks!

*I want to display contextual menu item in my 3 tabs activity (no view pager), just static tabs. The main activity is the ActionTab.listener. I used ActionBarActivity with action bar compat. The code for the main activity is below. I used the Google docs to attach and detach fragments (that are created if they are null the first time). Here is my LogCat, you can see that **onCreateOptionMenu is called for each existing fragment even when only one is attached and displayed** Why?*

LogCat:

V/MainActivity(22555): on create MainActivity *(application starts)*

V/onTabSelected(22555): starting

E/MainActivity(22555): frag 1 is null

V/onTabSelected(22555): add fragment 1 *(creates 1st fragment)*

D/Fragment1(22555): on Attach

D/Fragment1(22555): on create

D/Fragment1(22555):  - onCreateOPTIONMenu *(all is fine)*

D/Fragment1(22555): on create View

D/Fragment1(22555): on Activity Created

D/Fragment1(22555): on Start

D/Fragment1(22555): on Resume

D/dalvikvm(22555): GC_CONCURRENT freed 159K, 4% free 9115K/9415K, paused 1ms+2ms

D/CLIPBOARD(22555): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !

V/on Tab  Un-selected(22555): starting *(I selecte TAB2 : callback on unselect Tab1)*

V/on Tab 1 Unselected(22555): detach frag1 *(FragTransac.detach(frag1) has been passed)*

V/onTabSelected(22555): starting

E/MainActivity(22555): frag 2 is null *(ok that creates frag2)*

V/onTabSelected(22555): add fragment 2

D/Fragment2(22555): on Attach

D/Fragment1(22555):  - onCreateOPTIONMenu *(Why is it called, you are detached, frag1!)*

D/Fragment2(22555):  - onCreateOPTIONMenu *(frag2 ok)*

D/Fragment2(22555): on create

D/Fragment2(22555): on create View

D/Fragment2(22555): on Activity Created

D/Fragment2(22555): on Start

D/Fragment2(22555): on Resume

V/on Tab  Un-selected(22555): starting

V/on Tab 2 Unselected(22555): detach frag2

V/onTabSelected(22555): starting

E/MainActivity(22555): frag 3 is null

V/onTabSelected(22555): add fragment 3

D/Fragment3(22555): on Attach

D/Fragment1(22555):  - onCreateOPTIONMenu *(again problem)*

D/Fragment2(22555):  - onCreateOPTIONMenu *(problem repeated for frag2)*

D/Fragment3(22555):  - onCreateOPTIONMenu *(behavior I expect for frag3)*

D/Fragment3(22555): on create

D/Fragment3(22555): on Activity Created

D/Fragment3(22555): on Start

D/Fragment3(22555): on Resume

This is my main activity code: The main activity is the ActionTab.listener. I used ActionBarActivity with action bar compat. The code for the main activity is below. I used the Google docs to attach and detach fragments (that are created if they are null the first time).

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("MainActivity", "on create MainActivity");
    // Set the Action Bar to use tabs for navigation
    ab = getSupportActionBar();
    ab.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    tab1 = ab.newTab().setText("Tab 1").setTabListener(this);
    ab.addTab(tab1);
    tab2 = ab.newTab().setText("Tab 2").setTabListener(this);
    ab.addTab(tab2);
    tab3 = ab.newTab().setText("Tab 3").setTabListener(this);
    ab.addTab(tab3);
}

@Override
public void onResume(){ 
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate menu from menu resource (res/menu/main)
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

public boolean isInBooking() {
    return isInBooking;
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // This is called when a tab is selected.
    Log.v("onTabSelected", "starting");
    switch(tab.getPosition()){
    case 0: 

        if (frag1==null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "frag 1 is null");
            frag1 = new Fragment1();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag1);
            Log.v("onTabSelected", "add fragment 1");
        }else {
            ft.attach(frag1);
            Log.v("onTabSelected", "Attach fragment 1");
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (frag2==null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "frag 2 is null");
            frag2 = new Fragment2();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag2);
            Log.v("onTabSelected", "add fragment 2");
        } else {
            ft.attach(frag2);
            Log.v("onTabSelected", "Attach fragment 2");
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if (frag3==null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "frag 3 is null");
            frag3 = new Fragment3();
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, frag3);
            Log.v("onTabSelected", "add fragment 3");
        } else {
            ft.attach(frag3);
            Log.v("onTabSelected", "Attach fragment 3");
        }
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

// Implemented from ActionBar.TabListener
@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // This is called when a previously selected tab is unselected.
    Log.v("on Tab  Un-selected", "starting");
    switch(tab.getPosition()){
    case 0: 
        ft.detach(frag1);
        Log.v("on Tab 1 Unselected", "detach frag1");
        break;
    case 1:
        ft.detach(frag2);
        Log.v("on Tab 2 Unselected", "detach frag2");
        break;
    case 2:
        ft.detach( frag3);
        Log.v("on Tab 3 Unselected", "detach frag3");
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

The fragments are built as extension of Fragment. 
Here is the fragment onCreateOptionsMenu().
I put setHasOption to true. Maybe I should wraped this in a control as I saw on the CommonsWare example [here](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/ActionBar/src/com/commonsware/android/pagerbar/EditorFragment.java) but I don't understand how and why should I do that?

```
@Override 
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(android.view.Menu menu, android.view.MenuInflater inflater) {
    if(!isDetached()) {
        Log.d(TAG, " - onCreateOPTIONMenu");        
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment1, menu);
    } else Log.v(TAG, "not attached - onCreateOPTIONMenu"); 
}
```

I also tried **isAdded()** or **isHidden** with no  good results (always hidden, always added). But I do have calls detach and attach, What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is linked to this explanation: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-platform/QlkLMsncDwg/u3iZ-q7FCVkJ

In the end I left that simple implementation to go with a view pager that is more powerful and more refined, I feel. It natively manages correctly the menu  and provides nice animation transition.