# Need to remove a Fragment before orientation change, but does not go away. Why?

Tags: android, android-fragments

When my app is in landscape I need an extra fragment to show.

When the app changes back to portrait, the fragment does not go away and re-creates itself. Why?

Here is the sequence of FragmentActivity lifecycle methods that are the Launcher point for the app.

```
FragmentActivity onPause
FragmentActivity onDestroy
EditFragment onDestroy
EditFragment onCreate
FragmentActivity onCreate
FragmentActivity onResume
```

To initially add the fragment I use the following code in onCreate of FragmentActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle s) {
if(Util.isLandscape(Main.this) && mEditFragment == null) {
    mEditFragment = new EditFragment();
    mFragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    mFragTrans.replace(R.id.main_edit_frag, mEditFragment);
    mFragTrans.addToBackStack(null);
    mFragTrans.commit();
}
```

And the code used in onPause of the FragmentActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if(mEditFragment !=null) {
        mFragTrans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        mFragTrans.remove( mEditFragment);
        mFragTrans.commit();
    }
```

Comment: What happens if you **detach** your fragment?

Comment: It should not matter, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156406/whats-the-difference-between-detaching-a-fragment-and-removing-it

Comment: And what happens if you do force the immediate execution of your transaction **getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();**? (after your commit)

Comment: Actually I solved it. I believe the fragment pushed into the backstack was still around.

Comment: I had a last resort to try, but you solved it... it was "replace the fragment with **null**".