# Why doesn't detach() work on FragmentTransaction and remove() does?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm working on a `TabHost` whose tabs have associated a `Fragment` (each tab a different one). Each of those `Fragment`s have inside an instance of another `Fragment` which is a login bar that has two states: Logged in or not.

**Logged out example**

[image: Logged out]

**Logged in example**

[image: Logged in]

In layout terms, each of these states have associated a `View` (a `TextView` for the non-logged-in case and a `LinearLayout` for the logged-in case), so if one of them is `VISIBLE`, the other one is `GONE`. As per the tab content, this is an example of the code of one of them (`firsttab.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.android.gms.ads"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#0000FF"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <!-- That's the login bar -->
  <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/firsttab_loginrow"
    class="com.mydomain.myproject.LoginRowFragment"
    android:tag="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firsttab_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The inner Fragment (`com.mydomain.myproject.LoginRowFragment`) is defined this way:

```
<!-- If the user is not logged in -->
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/identification_nologin"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

<!-- if the user is logged in -->
<LinearLayout
   android:id="@+id/identification_didlogin"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >

   ...      
</LinearLayout>
```

A general schema would be something like this:

[image: Schema]

The problem comes when I'm handling the tab change event by either `attach()`ing or `detach()`ing the correspondent parent `Fragment` (in this case, `firsttab.xml`). Previously to attaching/detaching the parent, I try `detach()`ing the login `Fragment` (the inner one), but it doesn't fire the `onDetach()` callback. The same happens when `attach()`ing. The weird thing is that if I replace `.detach()` with `.remove()`, it works just fine.

```
@Override
public void onTabChanged(final String tag) {
  final TabInfo newTab = mTabInfo.get(tag);

  if (lastTab != newTab) {

    final FragmentTransaction ft = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    if ((lastTab != null) && (lastTab.getFragment() != null)) {

      // This is where it fails detaching. tabInfo is just a structure where I store some data
      // about the tabs to handle them. If I use remove() instead of the next detach() on loginFrag,
      // the onAttach()/onDetach() callbacks are not called. I'm quite sure everything is ok, loginFrag
      // is not null, it's actually the Fragment that should be detached, etc.

      final Fragment loginFrag = (Fragment) lastTab.getFragment().getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(lastTab.getLoginFragId());
      ft.detach(loginFrag);

      ft.detach(lastTab.getFragment());
    }

    if (newTab != null) {
      if (newTab.getFragment() == null) {
        final TabFragmentInflater tabInf = new TabFragmentInflater();
        newTab.setFragment(Fragment.instantiate(this, tabInf.getClass().getName(), newTab.getArgs()));
        ft.add(R.id.realtabcontent, newTab.getFragment(), newTab.getTag());
      }
      else
        ft.attach(newTab.getFragment());
    }

    ft.commit();
    this.getSupportFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

    lastTab = newTab;
  }
}
```

So the question is the following:

**Why** `onAttach()`/`onDetach()` callbacks are not fired in the `LoginRowFragment` class when using `.attach()` or `.detach()` on them, but get fired if I use `.add()` or `.remove()` respectively?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156406/whats-the-difference-between-detaching-a-fragment-and-removing-it

Comment: I know what's the difference, the question is why `.remove()` calls the `onDetach()` callback and `.detach()` doesn't in my case.

Comment: By logic it could be because state of the fragment with `.detach()` is managed by fragment manager (you don't care, manager will do everything), with `.remove` you lose everything and `onDetach` could be used to save state. (`onDetach` is called after `onDestroy`)

Comment: As I understand it, on both it should be fired `onDetach()`, independently if the state is saved or not. It's like the login bar `Fragment` wouldn't be detached because is held by something, but in the case this is the reason, I can't find out why.

Comment: Try not declaring your Fragment (login) in XML… instead create a proper transaction using the same FragmentManager.

Comment: do you use a animation on your Fragment's logic?

Comment: @deathember No animation there

Answer (score 4):

You cannot remove an instance of a Fragment which has been declared in your layout XML file (by design)

When you use FragmentTransactions, you're manipulating ViewGroups containing the layout of a Fragment.

When you declare your Fragment/Class in a layout, it's part of the View hierarchy, so you can't remove it.

You can, however, add a New Fragment into that layout, because it will act as a container.

Try changing your Layout from:

```
    <fragment 
      android:id="@+id/firsttab_loginrow"
      class="com.mydomain.myproject.LoginRowFragment"
      android:tag="1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

to:

```
    <FrameLayout 
      android:id="@+id/firsttab_loginrow"
      android:tag="1"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

And create a `FragmentTransaction` to add/replace/show/hide according to what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just did what you proposed, I changed the `fragment` to a `FrameLayout` and used `FragmentTransaction` to put the `fragment` inside via `.add()`: `final FragmentTransaction fth = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();`, `fth.add(R.id.firsttab_loginrow, new LoginRowFragment());`, `fth.commit();`. It renders the layout correctly, I can swap between tabs but same result, if I change `.remove()` to `.detach()` it still doesn't fire `onDetach()`. Weird...

Comment: Hmmm I think that the Tab Adapter may not be detaching it… (thinking)

Comment: I think that if the Activity is not stopped, it may be tied through the TabHost and therefore is not detached…

Comment: I'm of the same opinion, there must be something tying the `Activity`, but the question is why `.remove()` indeed removes the `Fragment` but `.detach()` doesn't? In my opinion it should do the same on both...

Comment: From documentation, it says that onAttach(Activity) is called once the fragment is associated with its activity and onDetach() is called immediately prior to the fragment no longer being associated with its activity. When you call detach(), the fragment is still being actively managed by the fragment manager which is not the case with remove. We use attach() only when the fragment is previously detached using detach() unlike add().

Comment: @Madala is correct. `onDetach` and `detach` are not referring to the same thing. Their names were poorly chosen.