# Saving answers before leaving fragment. [android]

Tags: android

I have a fragment, which have various questions. These question are fetched dynamically. Page does not have any save button. Pages answer(s) is saved once user navigate away from page. 
`onStop()` method is used to save the answer.

**Problem:** I have several question pages. So suppose user saves some answer in page one and quickly navigate to page 2 and page 3, answers are not getting saved. Below is the pictorial representation to explain

[image: Question]

My QuestionPagefragment onStop() method have these calls

```
public void onStop()
{
    super.onstop();
    new LongOperation().execute("");
}

 private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
          TaskAdapter adapter = TaskAdapter.getInstance();
          adpater.saveDataInCache();

          //create result
          adpater.updateResults();

          //update result
          adpater.updateDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

My question is, how do I save the result in onStop(). When I am adding a message dialog to indicate progress is going on, the message dialog comes up in main page not in the question page, as it is called on onStop;. Can anybody suggest me some thing .

Comment: try onDetach ... check this thread .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156406/whats-the-difference-between-detaching-a-fragment-and-removing-it

Comment: Moving this method in hierarchy will buy me some time, I am not sure about the amount of data thats required to be saved. Can you suggest me some way which will give me more specific results.

Comment: Why not simply move LongOperation to the holding Activity? Calling something like ((MyActivity)getActivity()).save() in onStop/onDetach

Comment: thats what I am doing, but when fragment is stopped and while answer is getting saved in background, u start and stop another fragment, its not saving for other fragment